# Is there a way in SQL to select rows until a column reaches a specific value?

Tags: sql

I have a dataset of customer profiles where I am trying to capture how much revenue they generated until they cancelled their subscription. The issue I am having is that after the customer cancels their subscription, the customer profile still exists in the database and registers as being charged 0. I am trying to create a visualization that shows each customers lifespan in a table up until the month that they cancel.

### Here is the data I have:

| customer name | customer id | cancelled | charge date | charged amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| gary | 012 | no | 1/1/2022 | 199 |
| gary | 012 | no | 2/1/2022 | 199 |
| gary | 012 | no | 3/1/2022 | 199 |
| gary | 012 | yes | 4/1/2022 | 199 |
| gary | 012 | no | 5/1/2022 | 199 |
| gary | 012 | no | 6/1/2022 | 199 |

I my desired output would select the first 4 lines above, and get rid of the last two.

I can pull up the data, but not sure where to go from there. So far I have:

```
select
t.customer_name,
t.customer_id,
t.cancel_flag,
t.revenue_date,
a.revenue,
a.customer_id
    from metrics t
inner join drp.mrr a
on t.customer_id= a.customer_id
```

Any ideas are much appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a window function to distinguish the rows before the cancellation and after it. For example:

```
select *
from (
  select
    t.customer_name,
    t.customer_id,
    t.cancel_flag,
    t.revenue_date,
    a.revenue,
    a.customer_id,
    max(t.cancel_flag) over(
      partition by t.customer_id 
      order by t.revenue_date
      rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
    ) as mc
  from metrics t
  inner join drp.daasity_mrr a on t.customer_id= a.customer_id
) x
where mc = 'no' or mc is null
```

Answer (score 0):

We can add a running total to see how much each customer paid so far.

```
select  *
       ,sum(charged_amount) over(partition by customer_id order by charge_date) as running_total
from
(
select  customer_name   
       ,customer_id 
       ,cancelled   
       ,charge_date
       ,case when count(case when cancelled = 'yes' then 1 end) over(partition by customer_id order by charge_date) = 0 then charged_amount end as charged_amount
from    t
) t
```

| customer_name | customer_id | cancelled | charge_date | charged_amount | running_total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| gary | 12 | no | 2022-01-01 | 199 | 199 |
| gary | 12 | no | 2022-02-01 | 199 | 398 |
| gary | 12 | no | 2022-03-01 | 199 | 597 |
| gary | 12 | yes | 2022-04-01 | null | 597 |
| gary | 12 | no | 2022-05-01 | null | 597 |
| gary | 12 | no | 2022-06-01 | null | 597 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/DR8uDda1)